# Overloaded constructor in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, constructor-overloading

I have the base class `Manager` and the derived class `Worker`, the inheritance seem to work properly - I've created a new object of the derived class using it's default constructor and i can output properly.
but now I want to make an overloaded constructor for the derived class (`Worker`) and there seem to be a compilation error, I tired to look for an answer but I didn't found one.
why the compiles says that `Worker` doesn't have id, name and salary fields? I've created a derived class by the book and created ctors for it.

`Manager` header:

```
#include <string>
#ifndef MANAGER_H
#define MANAGER_H

class Manager
{
public:
    Manager (); //ctor
    Manager (std::string, std::string, float, int); //overloaded ctor
    friend void display (Manager&); //friend function is declared
    ~Manager (); //dtor
protected:
    std::string id;
    std::string name;
    float salary;
private:
    int clearance;
};
```

`Manager` cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Manager.h"
#include "Worker.h"

Manager::Manager() //default ctor
{
id = "M000000";
name = "blank";
salary = 0;
clearance = 0;
}

Manager::Manager(std::string t_id, std::string t_name, float wage, int num): id (t_id), name      (t_name), salary(wage), clearance (num)
{
//overloaded ctor
}

Manager::~Manager()
{
 //dtor
}
```

`Worker` header:

```
#include <string>
#ifndef Worker_H
#define Worker_H

class Worker: public Manager
{
public:
    Worker();
    Worker (std::string, std::string, float, int);
    ~Worker();
     friend void display (Worker&); //friend function is declared
protected:
    int projects;
private:

};

#endif // Worker_H
```

`Worker` cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Manager.h"
#include "Worker.h"

Worker::Worker() //default ctor
{
id = "w000000";
name = " - ";
salary = 0;
projects = 0;

}
Worker::Worker(std::string t_id, std::string t_name, float wage, int num) : id (t_id), name (t_name), salary (wage), projects (num);
{
//ctor
}
Worker::~Worker()
{
//dtor
}
```

Comment: Classes should be responsible for initializing their own members. Delegate to a `Manager` constructor.

Comment: Why doesn't Worker's constructor call Manager's constructor in its initialization list?

Comment: not the topic of your question, but your model doesn’t seem to fit properly to inheritance. By your scheme, any worker is a manager (a worker can be used anywhere instead of a manager), which is not quite right.

Comment: @bolov I only did this for the experiment, but still a manager has a trait (`clearance`) that a worker doesn't, which sets the difference between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Worker::Worker(std::string t_id, std::string t_name, float wage, int num) : id (t_id), name (t_name), salary (wage), projects (num)
{
//ctor
}
```

here you initialize the members id,name, salary and clearance defined in base class. you need to pass it to the base class constructor for initialization. you cannot initialize them directly.
`id`, `name` and `clearance` are protected so you can access them in derived class but you cannot initialize them directly using initialization list. either you can `initialize inside the constructor` or `make a call to base constructor in initialization list`.

```
Worker::Worker(std::string t_id, std::string t_name, float wage, int num):Manager(t_id,t_name,wage,0), projects (num)
{
//ctor
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i used it and it worked.
if it is possible that you will explain to me some more about delegation of constructors.
as I understand the variables from the `Worker` ctor is passed to the `Manager` ctor.

Answer (score 0):

Derived classes don't see private members of their base class. You have to delegate the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Worker` constructors should be like:

```
Worker::Worker() : Manager("w000000", " - ", 0, 0) {}

Worker::Worker(std::string t_id, std::string t_name, float wage, int num) :
     Manager(t_id, t_name, wage, num)
{
}
```